# Do optional references in c++ preserve object life?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

Say I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/optional.hpp"
struct cat
{
    int paw = 4;
};

int main()
{
    boost::optional<cat&> z;
    {
        cat realCat = cat();
        z = realCat;
    }
    std::cout << z->paw << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, there's no reason to expect a consistent result to be printed, right, as the `realCat` was released by `}`? Or does the `optional` preserve the life of the `realCat`?

Comment: You do not understand life extension twice. In your code even regular const or rvalue reference will not extend lifetime.

Comment: One of those questions that make me cringe a little but I still upvote because it's a good question well asked, and in fact it's an issue I've admittedly shot myself in the foot with before. I still have a TODO in a code-base to refactor an interface to no longer optimize using `optional<T&>` because it's just too dangerous in general-purpose code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't, your code has undefined behavior when you try to print the value of `paw`.

The C++ rules for lifetime extension only apply when a *temporary* object is bound to an rvalue reference or lvalue reference to `const`, but `realCat` is not a temporary and binding it to an `optional` reference doesn't extend it's lifetime.

In any case, these lifetime extension rules don't apply to `boost::optional<T&>`. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/optional_references.html) for `boost::optional` mentions this:

> Rvalue references and lvalue references to const have the ability in C++ to extend the life time of a temporary they bind to. **Optional references do not have this capability** ...

As for `std::optional`, your program would be ill-formed if you tried to create `std::optional<T&>`.

[*[optional.syn]/1*](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.syn#1)

> A program that necessitates the instantiation of template `optional` for a reference type, or for possibly cv-qualified types `in_­place_­t` or `nullopt_­t` is ill-formed.

Comment: Ah, so 1Z makes these mistakes more unlikely.